# How to merge Vectors of Tuples without duplicates based on value in Tuple

Tags: rust

I have two Vectors of Tuples:

```rust
let nice_nums: Vec<(u16, u32)> = vec![(1, 10), (2, 11)];
let better_nums: Vec<(u16, u32)> = vec![(3, 12), (4, 13), (1, 8)];
```

I would like to merge `better_nums` with `nice_nums` but `better_nums` should take precedence. If the first value (u16) in any of the `better_nums` tuples matches any first value in the `nice_nums` tuple then the tuple that belongs to `better_nums` should take precedence and be added instead of the `nice_nums` tuple with the same key.

I tried to do this but I am not super familiar with Rust syntax:

```rust
// merged_numbers should be [(2, 11), (3, 12), (4, 13), (1, 8)]
let merged_numbers = better_nums.iter().map(|(a, b)| {
    for (i, j) in nice_nums {
        if i == a {
            return (a, b)
        }
        return (i, j)
    }
}).cloned().collect();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is the most idiomatic way in Rust, but this works:

```rust
fn main() {
    let nice_nums: Vec<(u16, u32)> = vec![(1, 10), (2, 11)];
    let better_nums: Vec<(u16, u32)> = vec![(3, 12), (4, 13), (1, 8)];

    // at the minimum, merged will include all of your `better_nums`
    let mut merged = better_nums.clone();
    
    nice_nums.iter().for_each(|&tup1| {
    
        // if the first element of our `nice_num` matches one of the `better_nums`
        // then do nothing. if there are no matches, add our `nice_num` to
        // `merged`
        for &tup2 in better_nums.iter() {
            if tup1.0 == tup2.0 {
                return;
            }
        }
        
        merged.push(tup1);
    });
    
    println!("{:?}", merged); // [(3, 12), (4, 13), (1, 8), (2, 11)]
}
```

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f956818d09b7b9e674f054489c35ad9d

Comment: Why `for_each()` when you can do `for ... in ...`?

Answer (score 2):

**If order doesn't matter**, you can use a `HashMap` as intermediary, inserting `better_nums` after to keep those values:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;
fn main() {
    let nice_nums: Vec<(u16, u32)> = vec![(1, 10), (2, 11)];
    let better_nums: Vec<(u16, u32)> = vec![(3, 12), (4, 13), (1, 8)];
    let result: Vec<(u16, u32)> = nice_nums
        .into_iter()
        .chain(better_nums.into_iter())
        .collect::<HashMap<u16, u32>>()
        .into_iter()
        .collect();
    
    println!("{result:?}");
}
```

> [(2, 11), (4, 13), (3, 12), (1, 8)]

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=831f186369d764fa2f5118ff4ced5afc)

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with iterators:

```
let nice_nums: Vec<(u16, u32)> = vec![(1, 10), (2, 11)];
let better_nums: Vec<(u16, u32)> = vec![(3, 12), (4, 13), (1, 8)];
let mut result = better_nums.clone();
result.extend(nice_nums.iter().copied().filter(|nice_tuple| {
    !better_nums
        .iter()
        .any(|better_tuple| better_tuple.0 == nice_tuple.0)
}));
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=eff411b5c991034348c3e956fa229350).